# Remover cabeçalho retorno Owin WebApi

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, owin

Uma consulta com retorno simples ao meu serviço REST traz a seguinte resposta:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Descricao": "TIROLESA DE AÇO",
  "Und": "UND",
  "Fabrica": "STARROW",
  "Estoque": 9,
  "Preco": 0.39
},
```

Porém a consulta com mais de um objeto inicia com `{"Result": [`

```
{
"Result":   
[
  {
    ....
    ....
    ....
  } 
],
  "Id": 3,
  "Exception": null,
  "Status": 5,
  "IsCanceled": false,
  "IsCompleted": true,
  "CreationOptions": 0,
  "AsyncState": null,
  "IsFaulted": false
}
```

Este último retorno traz um "cabeçalho" (`Result`) que dificulta a deserialização da minha classe, teria como configurar o retorno para que o mesmo venha somente o `Array JSON`, sem este cabeçalho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que o retorno do `JSON` com cabeçalho tem relação com a assinatura do método do WebApi que é chamado, por exemplo:

Se é um método `sincrono` `public List<Produto> GetAllProducts()` o retorno é:

```
[{
  "Id": 1,
  "Descricao": "TIROLESA DE AÇO",
  "Und": "UND",
  "Fabrica": "STARROW",
  "Estoque": 9,
  "Preco": 0.39
}]
```

Se é um método `assincrono` public `public Task<List<Produto>> GetAllProductsAsync()` o retorno é:

```
{
"Result":   
[
  {
    ....
    ....
    ....
  } 
],
  "Id": 3,
  "Exception": null,
  "Status": 5,
  "IsCanceled": false,
  "IsCompleted": true,
  "CreationOptions": 0,
  "AsyncState": null,
  "IsFaulted": false
}
```

Comment: Caso alguém tenha outra resposta eu desfaço esta como aceita.